# Which equivalent headers, functions, and data types do I need to replace while doing C socket programming on windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, environment

I have started C socket programming recently. After some days of learning, I wrote this program, which listens for connection on a specific IP and port:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main()
{
    printf ("The program has started\n");
    
    int sock, client_socket;
    char buffer[1024];
    char response[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_address;
    int i = 0;
    int optval = 1;
    socklen_t client_length;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error setting TCP socket options!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf ("TCP socket set successfully!\n");
    }

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.2.15");
    server_address.sin_port = htons(5005);

    int stat_check = bind (sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof (server_address));
    if (stat_check != 0)
    {
        printf ("Couldn't bind\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ("binded successfully\n");
    }
    
    stat_check = listen(sock, 5);
    if (!(stat_check == 0))
    {
        printf ("Failed to listen!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ("Listening...\n");
    }
    printf ("now the program will attempt to accept the connectionHSHA\n");
    client_length = sizeof(client_address);
    client_socket = accept (sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, &client_length);
    printf ("Socket Accepted or something happened\n");
    
    if (client_socket == -1)
    {
        printf ("Couldn't accept connection!\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf ("Connection Accepted!\n");
    }

    while (1)
    {
        jump:
        bzero(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        bzero(&response, sizeof(response));
        printf("* Shell#%s~$: ", inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr));
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        strtok(buffer, "\n");
        write(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        if (strncmp("q", buffer, 1) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            recv(client_socket, response, sizeof(response), MSG_WAITALL);
            printf("%s", response);
        }
    }
}
```

This program compiles 100% fine in my Linux system, but I need it to run on windows. When I compile the same program on my windows with the MinGW compiler, it runs into many missing-header errors. However, there are some libraries for socket programming in windows, such as `winsock.h`. But still when I replace `winsock.h` with `<sys/socket>` and remove other Linux libraries(`arpa/inet.h`, etc), there are some other errors like `socklen_t undefined`. I also receive some warnings.

Altogether, I am not clear which equivalent libraries, functions, and data types I need to replace if I want to run this code on windows. Or can I run it on windows in any other way? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the winsock.h documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/

Comment: Yes, Topoly. socklen_t seems to be at nowhere. I checked winsock.h, winsock2.h, sys/stats, and sys/types. They are probably in one of the other libraries, which are not supported on windows. Still, thank you!

Comment: Well yes, sockets are not part of the C standard, therefore windows can and will have their own separate definitions for the same things.

Comment: I didn't know that it is not a part of C standards. Then what is?

Comment: For sockets, there is nothing. How you use them is platform specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple but complete sample of a server servicing TCP with sockets under Windows.

It accept several simultaneous clients and serve them with a thread.
The server accept command lines from each client and echo them at server side (Easy to echo back to the client with a simple send). If the command is "exit" the server close the connection.

There are room for many enhancements of course. You've got the idea...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>

#define portNo 2100
#define MAX_CLIENTS 10

struct clientData {
    int    busy;
    int    inSocket;
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD  threadId;
};

struct clientData cliArray[MAX_CLIENTS];
int cliCount;

DWORD WINAPI ClientThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    struct clientData* cliData = (struct clientData*)lpParam;
    printf("[%d] Client start. Socket=%d\n", cliData->inSocket, cliData->inSocket);

    char buf[1024];
    int rcvLen;
    int rcvCount = 0;
    char ch;
    while (1) {
        rcvLen = recv(cliData->inSocket, &ch, 1, 0);
        if (rcvLen <= 0)
            break;
        if (ch == '\r')
            continue;      // Ignore return character (followed by '\n')
        if (ch != '\n') {
            putchar(ch);
            buf[rcvCount++] = ch;
            buf[rcvCount] = 0; // nul terminate string
        }
        else {
            printf("\n[%d] Line=\"%s\"\n", cliData->inSocket, buf);
            if (_stricmp(buf, "exit") == 0)
                break;
            rcvCount = 0;
            buf[0] = 0;
        }
    }

    closesocket(cliData->inSocket);

    printf("[%d] Client terminated.\n", cliData->inSocket);
    cliData->busy = 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    int srvSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (srvSocket < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Open socket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sockAddr;

    memset(&sockAddr, 0, sizeof(sockAddr));
    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(portNo);
    sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(srvSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bind socket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(srvSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (listen(srvSocket, 5)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "listen socket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(srvSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (1) {
        int inSocket = accept(srvSocket, NULL, NULL);
        if (inSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            fprintf(stderr, "accept socket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(srvSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        struct clientData* cliData = cliArray;
        int i = 0;
        while ((i < MAX_CLIENTS) && cliArray[i].busy)
            i++;
        if (i >= MAX_CLIENTS) {
            // To many clients, disconnect
            closesocket(inSocket);
            printf("Too many active clients (max=%d), discarding this one\n", MAX_CLIENTS);
            continue;
        }
        cliData = &cliArray[i];
        cliData->busy = 1;
        cliData->inSocket = inSocket;
        cliData->hThread = CreateThread(
            NULL,                            // default security attributes
            0,                               // use default stack size  
            ClientThreadFunction,            // thread function name
            cliData,                         // argument to thread function 
            0,                               // use default creation flags 
            &cliData->threadId);             // returns the thread identifier 
    }

    closesocket(srvSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    printf("Done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```